# How to get mvn dependecy tree to filter dependencies with specific version

Tags: java, maven

Are there any maven commands which helps me to filter dependency tree for a specific version.
Eg: I have http client **`4.5.1,4.5.2,4.5.3`**  jar versions coming from different pom.

I can get the tree by filtering

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore
```

If I have lot of dependencies which uses old versions , then excluding those makes tedious and clumsy for a multi module project ***instead if we have an extra filter to filter only 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 dependencies separately it would make our work ease.***.

> Note these are the transitive dependencies and if I use exclude on
>   transitive dependencies using enforcer plugin  it will not download
>   the latest jar also since I have not used dependency management in my
>   pom

What I need is transitive depedency should download the version which I need instead of older version.I cannot modify transitive dependency pom.

Any one who can shed some light would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look into the [maven-enforcer-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html)

We use it to ensure some dependency will not be used. E.g.

```
 <plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <bannedDependencies>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>commons-collections:commons-collections:[3.2.1]</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </bannedDependencies>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Hi Chistian I have modified the question .I need this for transitive dependencies .I saw bannedTransitiveDependencies as well but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You could use grep:

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore |grep "4.5.1"
```

Comment: hi Ivo grep will simply search the version .I need dependecy tree with version .I mean which dependecy is downloading what version.One more thing since I am using windows grep will not be useful  I tried findstr for windows.Thanks for your help